# DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA(schema => '<SCHEMA_NAME>', compile_all => FALSE) doesn't compile invalid package bodies

Tags: oracle, plsql

The call of

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA(schema => '<SCHEMA_NAME>', compile_all => FALSE);
END;
/
```

doesn't compile invalid package bodies. Does anybody know the reason?

(Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production)

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't try, but they have some actual error? Do you have anything in `user_errors`?

Comment: @Alex Poole There's no error in `user_errors`.

Comment: How about `all_errors` or `dba_errors` then, if the invalid package isn't in your own schema? Why do you think it isn't being recompiled, and why was it invalid in the first place - and have you changed something that means it should now be valid, and would be valid if explicitly compiled with `alter package ... compile`?

Comment: @Alex Poole No Errors in `dba_errors`. After a `ALTER PACKAGE <package> COMPILE` the package becomes valid. The package uses a database link referencing a remote user defined type. The database link is valid.

Comment: Hmm, I can't duplicate this with a package invalidated by a dependency either. Are you able to reproduce it now you've compiled the package? Do you know exactly why it was invalid?

Comment: The package was invalid since I changed an attribute of a table. I figured out that the problem is the remote referenced (DB link) user type. Although the DB link is valid the package body does not become valid after calling `DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA(schema => '<SCHEMA_NAME>', compile_all => FALSE)`.

Answer (score 9):

It does; at least in 11.2.0.3, so I suppose there could have been a bug in the base release.

if I create an invalid package, in this case because it refers to a table that doesn't exist:

```
create package p42 as
  procedure test;
end p42;
/

PACKAGE P42 compiled

create package body p42 as
  procedure test is
    n number;
  begin
    select count(*) into n from t42;
  end test;
end p42;
/

PACKAGE BODY P42 compiled
Errors: check compiler log
```

And then check the status and last DDL time:

```
select object_type, object_name, status, last_ddl_time
from user_objects where object_name = 'P42'
order by object_type, object_name;

OBJECT_TYPE         OBJECT_NAME          STATUS  LAST_DDL_TIME      
------------------- -------------------- ------- -------------------
PACKAGE             P42                  VALID   2015-03-02 17:39:42 
PACKAGE BODY        P42                  INVALID 2015-03-02 17:39:42
```

And then recompile the schema and check again:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA(schema => USER, compile_all => FALSE);
END;
/

anonymous block completed

select object_type, object_name, status, last_ddl_time
from user_objects where object_name = 'P42'
order by object_type, object_name;

OBJECT_TYPE         OBJECT_NAME          STATUS  LAST_DDL_TIME      
------------------- -------------------- ------- -------------------
PACKAGE             P42                  VALID   2015-03-02 17:39:42 
PACKAGE BODY        P42                  INVALID 2015-03-02 17:39:49
```

.. the last DDL time has changed, so it was recompiled. It's still invalid as I haven't fixed the underlying problem. And I can see the

```
select text from user_errors where name = 'P42';

TEXT                                                        
------------------------------------------------------------
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist              
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Or if your `'<SCHEMA_NAME>'` isn't your current user, it will be in `all_errors`, if it's still invalid.

If I create the missing table and compile the schema again:

```
create table t42 (id number);

Table t42 created.

BEGIN
    DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA(schema => USER, compile_all => FALSE);
END;
/

anonymous block completed

select object_type, object_name, status, last_ddl_time
from user_objects where object_name = 'P42'
order by object_type, object_name;

OBJECT_TYPE         OBJECT_NAME          STATUS  LAST_DDL_TIME      
------------------- -------------------- ------- -------------------
PACKAGE             P42                  VALID   2015-03-02 17:39:42 
PACKAGE BODY        P42                  VALID   2015-03-02 17:40:11
```

... the last DDL time has changed again, as has the status now. If I compile again, with your `compile_all => FALSE` flag, then the last DDL time won't change as it won't look at the valid package.